# Telling a component to rerender itself via the parent

Tags: ember.js

I have various ember components on a screen.  The components are stored in a grid using gridster.js.  When you resize a box in gridster you can access when the box was resized using the stop function.

```
export default Ember.View.extend(Ember.Evented,{

    setupGridster : function() {
        $(".gridster ul").gridster({
            widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140],
            widget_margins: [5, 5],
            helper: 'clone',
            resize: {
                enabled: true,
                max_size: [4, 4],
                min_size: [1, 1],
                start: function(e, ui, $widget) {

                },

                resize: function(e, ui, $widget) {

                },

                stop: function(e, ui, $widget) {
                    self.trigger('widget:resize:stop');
                    console.log('widget:resize:stop');
                }
            }
        }).data('gridster');

    ...
```

In the component I have:

```
this.on('widget:resize:stop', this, 'rerender');
```

but the component does not seem to have the 'widget:resize:stop' event in scope so the code is never executed.

1. How do I give each component access to the 'widget:resize:stop' event.
2. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When 'listening' to an event using `on()` you need to get the instance of the thing triggering the method and call the `on` method on that object.

It's hard to know exactly what object you need to find because I don't know the tree of your components/views, but if the aforementioned components' parent is the `Em.View` code above, you should listen for:

```
this.get('parentView').on('widget:resize:stop', this, this.rerender);
```

Also, make sure you're calling the `on` in a method like willInsertElement or didInsertElement. For example:

```
watchForResize: function() {
    this.get('parentView').on('widget:resize:stop', this, this.rerender);
}.on('willInsertElement'),
```